# Solve the equation $\frac{1}{x^2+11x-8} + \frac{1}{x^2+2x-8} + \frac{1}{x^2-13x-8} = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem**

Solve the equation $$\frac{1}{x^2+11x-8} + \frac{1}{x^2+2x-8} + \frac{1}{x^2-13x-8} = 0$$

**What I've tried**

First I tried factoring the denominators but only the second one can be factored as $(x+4)(x-2)$.

Then I tried substituting $y = x^2 - 8$ but that didn't lead me anywhere.

**Where I'm stuck**

I don't know how to start this problem. Any hints?

P.S. I would really appreciate it if you give me *hints* or at least hide the solution. Thanks for all your help in advance!

Comment: While it's only a hint and not a solution, it is always not a bad idea to make a graph (DESMOS) just to see what is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started very well. To make things easier, set $A=x^2+7x-8$ (*) and the equation rewrites
$$\frac{1}{A+4x} + \frac{1}{A-5x} + \frac{1}{A-20x} = 0.$$

Denominators are not allowed to be zeros. We solve
$$(A-5x)(A-20x)+(A+4x)(A-20x)+(A+4x)(A-5x)=0$$
or equivalently
$$3A^2-42Ax=0,$$ or even
$$3(x^2+7x-8)(x^2-7x-8)=0,$$
which is easy to finish.

(*) I noticed that $x=1$ satisfies, and decided to make profit from it.

Answer (score 5):

Since you require the sum to be zero, all you need is to compute the numerator of the LHS when put over a common denominator, since regardless of the value of the denominator--as long as it is nonzero--the LHS is zero only if the numerator is zero.  Then once you solve for the roots of the numerator, check the validity of the solution set by substitution.